# How to Prevent Users From Taking Screenshots in React-Js Website

Tags: reactjs

How to Prevent Users From Taking Screenshots in React-Js Website
Can we block windows +print screen in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way you're going to code something into your webpage that will prevent the user from using their OS to take a screenshot of their screen.  You will need to think of better security measures.